# Transform several vectors in one list of lists

Tags: r, list, vector

I am looking for a way to turn several vectors of the same length into a list of named lists.

For example if I have vectors:

```
v1 <- c("a", "b", "c")
v2 <- c("x", "y", "z")
```

, list should be:

```
list(
  list(
    name = "a",
    value = "x"
  ),
  list(
    name = "b",
    value = "y"
  )
  list(
    name = "c",
    value = "z"
  )
)
```

This can be useful when you generate request body for APIs that take several records in one request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
l <- mapply(
  function(name, value) list(name = name, value = value),
  v1, v2,
  USE.NAMES = FALSE, 
  SIMPLIFY = FALSE
)
str(l)

# List of 3
# $ :List of 2
#  ..$ name : chr "a"
#  ..$ value: chr "x"
# $ :List of 2
#  ..$ name : chr "b"
# ..$ value: chr "y"
# $ :List of 2
#  ..$ name : chr "c"
#  ..$ value: chr "z"
```

Comment: Code golf: `Map(list,name=v1,value=v2)`.

Comment: @r2evans that is really great, only little problem it gives names to the lists.

Comment: yes, that works. I like idea of having my own list function as well

Comment: `Map(list,name=v1,value=v2,USE.NAMES=F)`. Barely less-golfy :-)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is `pmap` from `purrr`

```
purrr::pmap(list(name = v1, value = v2), list)
```